# Saving work automatically when battery is low

Tags: bash, scripts, battery, automation

I am a writer and of course I sometimes lose my work if the battery goes dead. I am looking for suggestions for ways to save when the battery gets to 5% or 1%.  Maybe a bash command written to save text and Libra documents at a certain percentage of battery? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you make it hibernate at 15%? That will save your session.

Comment: So you mean to save your work while the computer is running? Because if the battery depletes while the computer is in standby, there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two easy methods for this

1) Pay attention to battery percentage?
2) Use Libre Office's autosave feature. The screenshot below shows the setting's location the options menu:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A script in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

apps_to_save = ['Gedit', 'Writer']

battery_limit = 10  # in percent

def get_battery_percentage():

    percentage, err = subprocess.Popen([r'upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep --color=never -E percentage | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed s/%//
'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

    return(int(percentage))

while True:

    if get_battery_percentage() <= battery_limit:

        for app in apps_to_save:

            app_window_ids = subprocess.Popen(['xdotool', 'search', '--class', app],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            out, err = app_window_ids.communicate()

            for app_window_id in out.splitlines():

                subprocess.Popen(['xdotool', 'windowactivate', app_window_id,
                ';', 'xdotool', 'key', 'ctrl+s'], shell=True)
```

By default, it saves all Gedit and LibreOffice Writer windows when battery reaches 10%.

You can add things to the `apps_to_save` list by modifying that line like:

```
apps_to_save = ['Gedit', 'Writer', 'SomeOtherApp']
```

And change the `battery_limit` to whatever percentage you want to save on. (But don't add a `%` sign - just the number)

It would also be trivial to change this into something that saves every ten minutes or so - no matter what battery percentage.