# How to shutdown system if not charging

Tags: 14.04, power-management, shutdown, cron

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My battery is not working, i.e. it provides backup for around 5 minutes.
Now when I download stuff, it sometimes takes around 5 - 6 hours. And I can't just hang around the laptop for so long.
So I wish to make a code, that will check if battery is charging every 5 minutes, and if not, it will shutdown the system.

Comment: Any other requirements other than shutdown when fully charged ?

Comment: Also, do you use the default desktop, Unity ?

Comment: Answer posted, let me know what you think or if you need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script bellow uses two calls to `dbus` and one while loop to poll for the percentage. Very simple and effective setup. Run this when you want to shutdown the laptop once it is charged

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
get_percentage()
{
  qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power \
       /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
        org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Percentage
}

shutdown_system()
{
  qdbus com.canonical.Unity  \
       /com/canonical/Unity/Session \
        com.canonical.Unity.Session.Shutdown

}

# Basically loop that waits till
# battery reaches 100%. When 100%
# reached , loop exits, and next command
# is executed, which is shutdown
while [ $(get_percentage) -ne 100   ] ;
do
  sleep 0.25
done

# Add delay or a warning message here if necessary
shutdown_system
```

Comment: @ShohanDebnath: Answer accepted by you, but is not adding a condition on 'download-end' necessary in yr use-case ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this python script. It borrows from [Saving work automatically when battery is low](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759044/saving-work-automatically-when-battery-is-low/759052#759052)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import dbus

sys_bus = dbus.SystemBus()

ck_srv = sys_bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit',
                            '/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager')
ck_iface = dbus.Interface(ck_srv, 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager')

stop_method = ck_iface.get_dbus_method("Stop")

battery_limit = 90  # in percent

def get_battery_percentage():

    percentage, err = subprocess.Popen([r'upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep --color=never -E percentage | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sed s/%//
'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

    return(int(percentage))

while True:

    if get_battery_percentage() <= battery_limit:

        stop_method()
```